# How to report old scores with GameKit?

Tags: iphone, ios, gamekit

I'm thinking of adding GameKit support to my iOS game, and I'd like to still give credit to players for the high scores they got before I added GameKit. I noticed that the date property of GKScore is readonly, and it seems to be automatically set to the current date and time.  Is there a way I can report old scores to GameKit's leaderboards, including the old timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My conclusion is that there is currently (as of iOS 4.3.3) no Apple-sanctioned way to do this.

I think I could do some casting sourcery (oh what a pun!) on GKScore to force in the timestamp I want, but I'm afraid Apple might reject the app.  My plan is to simply drop old scores once I add GameKit support.